# How does deja vu work?

Tags: psychology, biology, neurology

> If you've ever had that fleeting,
>   mysterious sense that something new --
>   a city or person you’re seeing for the
>   first time -- is somehow familiar,
>   that you’ve been there or known them
>   before, then you can count yourself
>   among those who have experienced déjà
>   vu. It’s typically a brief sensation,
>   lasting no more than 10 to 30 seconds,
>   but 96 percent of the population
>   claims to have experienced at least
>   one occurrence. [source](http://www.physorg.com/news185192263.html)

Obviously, many people worldwide think the deja vu is real and claim to have experienced it, but has it ever been proven to exist under proper observing conditions?

If so, is there a scientific (physiological, neurological, psychological etc) explanation for the phenomenon?

Comment: Think about what you are asking: "Does [a feeling] exist?". Maybe you just want to stick with the request for an explanation.

Comment: In order to determine whether people have experienced something like that, you ask people.  Self-reporting isn't real accurate but it's what we've got for subjective experiences.  For reality...what specifically are you asking is real?  Have I known a place I didn't know, and how do you test that?

Comment: Agreed: remove the first part of the question. It's about as useful as asking whether anyone has ever been truly happy.

Comment: It's a glitch in the [Matrix](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z_KmNZNT5xw), dude.

Comment: I get it a lot in Stack Overflow...

Comment: Yep, had quite a lot of them. As a little kid, I wondered if I was psychic or something, but then I realized that it didn't really work that way :D

Comment: It's just a glitch in your brain where you process what you're seeing as a memory, giving you the impression you've seen something before. Sort of like a short-circuit. You'll notice, for example, that it only ever happens in days following a poor night's sleep, when the brain isn't properly rested.

Comment: I'm sure I've seen this question somewhere before.

Comment: @matt_black You have seen this kind of question before, and it is just an Occam's Razor question.... Imagine you take a trip to an exotic city in a foreign country.  Suddenly you are finding some of the skylines and buildings familiar.  Now which explanation requires the fewest crazy assumptions (1) Reincarnation/Past Lives, (2) brain is being sucked into a Klein bottle briefly while virtual scenes are constructed for your future viewing, (3) brain is imperfectly recalling forgotten images from say, a spy movie or a news broadcast.

Comment: I get dreams that turn into deja vu. Makes it very difficult not to believe in woo.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

From [HowStuffWorks](http://science.howstuffworks.com/science-vs-myth/extrasensory-perceptions/deja-vu.htm):

[image: Deja Vu]

> **There are more than 40 theories as to
>   what déjà vu is and what causes it**,
>   and they range from reincarnation to
>   glitches in our memory processes.
>
> **Déjà vu is extremely difficult to
>   study because it occurs briefly,
>   unannounced, only in certain people,
>   and has no witnesses** or physical
>   manifestations other than the person
>   saying, "Hey, déjà vu!" Because of
>   this, **there is little firm research
>   and no definitive explanations**.

> Firmly placing déjà vu within the
>   study of memory, [researchers] hope to discover
>   more about how memories are formed,
>   stored and retrieved.
>
> They have since determined that the
>   **medial [temporal lobe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporal_lobe)** is involved in
>   our conscious memory.

---

### Double Perception (Divided Attention) Theory

> ... **when we are distracted with
>   something else, we subliminally take
>   in what's around us but may not truly
>   register it consciously**. Then, when we
>   are able to focus on what we are
>   doing, those surroundings appear to
>   already be familiar to us even when
>   they shouldn't be.

- [SMU Research (Alan Brown, Elizabeth Marsh)](http://blog.smu.edu/research/2009/06/d233j224_vu_research_pushed_ar.html)
- [An illusion of memory: False recognition influenced by unconscious perception](http://psycnet.apa.org/index.cfm?fa=buy.optionToBuy&id=1989-31882-001)
- [New York Times article](http://www.nytimes.com/2004/09/14/science/14deja.html?_r=1&pagewanted=print&position=)

---

### The Hologram Theory

> Dutch psychiatrist **Herman Sno proposed
>   the idea that memories are like
>   holograms**, meaning that you can
>   recreate the entire three-dimensional
>   image from any fragment of the whole.
>   The smaller the fragment, however, the
>   fuzzier the ultimate picture.
>
> **Déjà vu ... happens when some
>   detail in the environment we are
>   currently in** (a sight, sound, smell,
>   et cetera) **is similar to some remnant
>   of a memory of our past and our brain
>   recreates an entire scene from that
>   fragment**.

- [Newsweek - A Fresh View Of Deja Vu](http://www.newsweek.com/1991/01/06/a-fresh-view-of-deja-vu.html)
- [Scientific American - What exactly is déjà vu?](http://www.scientificamerican.com/article.cfm?id=what-exactly-is-dj-vu)

---

### Dual Processing (Delayed Vision) Theory

> **Robert Efron** tested an idea at the
>   Veterans Hospital in Boston in 1963
>   that stands as a valid theory today.
>
> **He proposed that a delayed
>   neurological response causes déjà vu**.
>
> Because information enters the
>   processing centers of the brain via
>   more than one path, it is possible
>   that occasionally that blending of
>   information might not synchronize
>   correctly.

- [Robert Efron - TEMPORAL PERCEPTION, APHASIA AND DÉJÀ VU](http://brain.oxfordjournals.org/content/86/3/403.extract)

---

### **[Origin of Deja Vu pinpointed?](http://www.livescience.com/1589-origin-deja-vu-pinpointed.html)**

> ... a new study suggests only a small
>   chunk of [the [hippocampus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hippocampus), called **the [dentate gyrus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dentate_gyrus),
>   is responsible for “episodic”
>   memories—information that allows us to
>   tell similar places and situations
>   apart**.
>
> When Susumu Tonegawa and his team bred
>   mice without a fully-functional
>   dentate gyrus, the rodents struggled
>   to tell the difference between two
>   similar but different situations.

- [MIT News](http://web.mit.edu/newsoffice/2007/deja-vu-0607.html)
- [Study: Anatomical origin of déjà vu and vivid 'memories' in human temporal lobe epilepsy](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8149215)

---

More to read:

- [Discover Magazine - The Psychology of Déjà Vu](http://discovermagazine.com/2005/sep/psychology-of-deja-vu)

Comment: Great answer... I just wish it also explained why sometimes I not only have deja vu, but also deja vu about having deja vu about the situation. I've had that happen a few (distinct) times. I don't think I've ever gone another layer deep, though - that is, having deja vu about having deja vu about having deja vu about the current situation.